# How to exit a fullscreen video programmatically on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, html5-video, fullscreen

I need to close a fullscreen video at it's end.

This code works with iOS but not with Android

```
$("#myvideo").on("ended", function() {
    this.webkitExitFullScreen();
});
```

Is there a way to close the video programmatically on Android ?

Answer (score 0):

To Exit from Full screen try this.

getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

ActivitiesCurrentContentView.requestLayout();

Comment: I have replaced `this.webkitExitFullScreen();` by your code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The question is about HTML/JavaScript issue, while answer is for Android SDK developers.